# Gnome: cairo-dock keeps weird position after complete reinstall

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, cairo-dock

I am running gnome desktop on Arch linux. In this case, I am booting from a USB flash drive. Probably by battery outage in suspend mode,  cairo-dock` started displaying as a very small icon in the top left corner of the screen. It is unresponsive, and can't be repositioned neither via ALT-/CTRL-drag&drop nor via the cairo-dock config file.

So I completely uninstalled `cairo-dock`, `cairo-dock-plug-ins` and removed the cairo-dock folder in `~/.config/`. I rebooted and reinstalled everything. The result keeps the same as pictured in this screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Also, even restoring the complete home folder from an earlier backup did not help.

How can I fix this back to "normal", i. e. `cairo-dock` being on the bottom of the screen?